# How many verses to read in Salah or only full Surahs?

Tags: salat

Salam

In Salah are we supposed to only recite full surahs? Or can we recite just some verses from the middle of surah. For example can I recite ayat al kursi in 1st rakah and then verses 1-5 of Surah al baqarah in 2nd rakah?

I only know about 5-6 Surahs from memory and would like to recite something different.

Thanks

Comment: Wa alaikum Salaam. Which madhab do yiu follow? I think there are differences here. I follow Hanafi.

Comment: Well I’ve been taught to pray the Hanafi way but don’t really know much else about the madhabs. I’m trying to learn more and etc but I only just pray my salahs and read Quran etc. Well verses 1-5 of Surah baqarah first page is more then 3 verses and ayat al kursi is little a long Is this ok?

Comment: This question should have at least one answer on the site.

Comment: I’m new to the site

Answer (score 1):

Wa alaikum salaam

I'll answer based on my knowledge of the rules within the Hanafi madhab. There are finer details you probably don't need to worry about too much, so I'll cover the high level basics.

Besides Surah Fatiha, you should recite at least one long verse or three short verses in each ruku. There are details as to what long and short are, but I recommend you avoid these by choosing three verses. The exception is if you want to recite the last verse of Baqarah for example, which is clearly long, and one I'd highly recommend.

In Hanafi, you are allowed to recite different surahs even within the same ruku. Avoid reciting two surahs, while skipping the one between them. Avoid reciting in reverse order.

I reiterate there might be differences with other madhabs.

Comment: Well I’ve been taught to pray the Hanafi way but don’t really know much else about the madhabs. I’m trying to learn more and etc but I only just pray my salahs and read Quran etc. Well verses 1-5 of Surah baqarah first page is more then 3 verses and ayat al kursi is little a long Is this ok?

Comment: Yes that's enough.

Comment: Thank you puts my mind at rest that I’m doing right